# Condition for which f(B_t) is a martingale

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

How can we find all functions g such that $g(B_t)$ is a martingale? (assume g(x) is twice continuously differentiable).  Let $X_t$ = $g(B_t)$, by using the Ito formula, I get

$dX_t$ = $f_{B}'$($B_t$)$dB_t$ + $\frac{1}{2}$$f_{BB}''$($B_t$)dt, then by integrating both sides, I obtain X$_t$ = g(t) + $\frac{1}{2}$$g_{B}'$(B$_t$) $-$ $\frac{1}{2}$$g_{B}'$(0).  It requires that $\textbf{E}$[X$_t$|$\mathcal{F}_s$] = X$_s$ for t $\geq$ s.

It follows that we need $\textbf{E}$[g(t) - g(s) + $\frac{1}{2}$[$g_B'$(B$_t$) - $g_B'$(B$_s$)] | $\mathcal{F}_s$] = 0.

Is it correct?  Not sure how to continue to solve it. Any suggestion?

Comment: MathJax works much better when you put an entire math expression between the `$` signs, not just individual symbols.  For instance, instead of writing  `g(B$_t$)` as you have done, write `$g(B_t)$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your integration of both sides doesn't make any sense to me.  You should get
$$X_t = g(0) + \int_0^t g'(B_s)\,dB_s + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t g''(B_s)\,ds$$
and then observe that a martingale has zero bounded variation part, so you will get a martingale only if the last term on the right side vanishes.  You also need to ensure that the $dB_s$ term is a martingale, and not just a local martingale.  That should give you an idea of an appropriate condition on $g$...

Comment: Ok, then I use your above formula to compute E[$X_t$| $\mathcal{F}_s$] = X$_s$ + $\frac{1}{2}$E $\int_{s}^{t}$g''(B$_u$)du.  So I need the second term equal to zero. How to connect it with property of g?

Comment: @Jonny: $g'' \equiv 0$ is certainly sufficient - and if you work a little harder, you can show it is also necessary.

Comment: @NateEldredge I've been thinking about this question as well and am suck on the necessary condition, I have computed $0=E[X_{t}-X_{s}|\mathcal{F}_{s}]= E[ \int^{t}_{s} (g'(B_{u}) - \frac{1}{2}g''(B_{u}))dB_{u}|\mathcal{F}_{s}] $ but am am having  trouble seeing the implication that $g''=0$.

Comment: @user135520: First of all, the second term of the integral should be $du$, not $dB_u$.  The first term is a martingale, so its conditional expectation vanishes and you have $0 = \frac{1}{2} E[\int_s^t g''(B_u)\,du \mid \mathcal{F}_s] = \frac{1}{2} \int_s^t E[g''(B_u) \mid \mathcal{F}_s]\,du$.  By the fundamental theorem of calculus, this shows $0 = E[g''(B_s) \mid \mathcal{F}_s] = g''(B_s)$ a.s for every $s$.  Since the distribution of $B_s$ has full support, this can only happen if $g'' \equiv 0$.

Comment: I see, I misinterpreted Ito's formula and I think I would have missed the application of the FTC due to unfamiliarity of the objects here but you are thinking of $E[g''(B_{u})$ as a function of $u$. Thank you!